# copy paste Illustration shapes to word document from another word document using open xml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, shapes

i want copy word illustration (shapes) from source document to destination document with source style and formatting following code do same but if destination document content any existing data that is being removed.
i used following code

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = true;
        // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc1 = oWord.Documents.Add();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDocDest = oWord.Documents.Open(@"E:\Docx\temp4.docx");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDocSour = oWord.Documents.Open(@"E:\Docx\q3.docx");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range oRangeSrc = oDocSour.Content;
        oRangeSrc.Copy();

        if (oDocDest.Paragraphs.Count > 0)
        {
            object docStart = oDocDest.Paragraphs.Count;
            object docEnd = oDocDest.Paragraphs.Count + 1;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range oRangeDst = oDocDest.Range(ref docStart, ref docEnd);
            oRangeDst.PasteSpecial(DataType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
        }
```

content should be paste after any paragraph or content if exist any

Comment: The code included in the question has nothing to do with "open xml". The code shown uses "the interop". So it's really clear what it is you're asking. Assuming you simply don't understand what "open xml" and the interop are, and you mean the interop... This line is specifying the *entire document content*: `oRangeDst = oDocDest.Range(ref docStart, ref docEnd);` Use `docEnd` for both parameters to go to the end of the document.

Comment: THANKS CINDY MEISTER , yes code is using office interop im looking for both solutions i.e. office & open xml

Comment: Value out of range, error when its set to docend ref

Comment: Then try docEnd-1 for the first parameter